# Firebase with Robolectric

Tags: android, firebase, robolectric

I'm trying to write few tests for Firebase with Robolectric. But Firebase callbacks are never invoked. e.g.

```
@Test
public void testFirebaseCallback() {
    Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_API_URL);
    firebase.child("custom_child").setValue("custom_value", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
            System.out.println("never goes here");
        }
    });

    sleep(10);
}
```

My Robolectric config:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 16)
```

fyi. my calls didn't hit Firebase server without 5sec "sleep". With "sleep" - calls hit the server but callbacks are never invoked.

[firebase](https://www.firebase.com)

Comment: If you break running test, where it end ups?

Comment: when i'm using firebase sdk for JVM - i'm receiving callbacks. compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.4.1+'